# Install Error while installing Google Apps marketplace app

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

We've been getting this installation error when our users try to install the apps marketplace app. [image: Error while installing marketplace app]

How do we resolve this?

Comment: Have you made any recent changes in your app? Did you change the scopes?

Answer (score 0):

Is the error being seen by Google Apps domain administrators or non-admin domain users? If its latter then its likely the domain administrator has not enabled install for non-admin users in the domain.

Comment: No we are seeing this error for Google Apps domain administrators. A non-admin user can't even start the installation of a domain wide marketplace app.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue but do not know how to resolve this.

We had tried to update our marketplace app manifest file but due to some issue on Google's end, the updated manifest file was not being uploaded and this error was being thrown

```
 This item is not an app, please remove app section from manifest , google apps marketplace
```

So we removed the "app" section from the manifest file and uploaded it. This has resulted in our marketplace app becoming a Chrome extension rather than a marketplace app and causing the issue.

Currently if I try to edit and upload a version of manifest file with "app" section, it won't allow me to upload it, showing the same error as before. So there is no way that I know which can solve this issue.

If anyone can help me out with this it will be really helpful. Registering a new MP app, getting approval from google and moving all users and reviews to new app will be really painful.